# DIfferent ways exist to create object attributes outside of init method based on the initial attributes

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm trying to understand OOP (specifically, in Python 3). Here's a basic class template:

```
class Lines:
    """
    Arguments: list of coordinates
    """

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.x1 = points[0]
        self.y1 = points[1]
        self.x2 = points[2]
        self.y2 = points[3]
```

I pass starting and ending (x,y) coordinates in a list to the class.
However, I want to also add a *length*, *slope*, and *y-intercept* attribute to the objects of this class `Lines` (**Note**: I do ***not*** want them as methods). Here are a couple ways I found to do so-

#### Add to the init method itself

```
class Lines:

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.x1 = points[0]
        self.y1 = points[1]
        self.x2 = points[2]
        self.y2 = points[3]
        
        ##Create length, slope, and y_intercept attributes

        self.length = round(((self.x2-self.x1)**2 + (self.y2-self.y1)**2) ** 0.5, 2) 
        self.slope = round((self.y2 - self.y1)/(self.x2-self.x1),1)
        self.y_intercept = self.y1 - self.slope*self.x1
```

#### Create methods for them and use the @property decorator

```
class Lines:

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.x1 = points[0]
        self.y1 = points[1]
        self.x2 = points[2]
        self.y2 = points[3]
        
    @property    
    def length(self):
        return round(((self.x2-self.x1)**2 + (self.y2-self.y1)**2) ** 0.5, 2)

    @property        
    def slope(self):
        return round((self.y2 - self.y1)/(self.x2-self.x1),1)

    @property
    def y_intercept(self):
        return self.y1 - self.slope*self.x1
```

#### My Issues:

I don't prefer the first method (using `init()`) because it just looks a little cumbersome to fit calculation-based code like that in there. My understanding is that the init method is just there to initialize the attributes of the object and not for much more than that.

I can use the property decorator and then access the objects' slopes etc like so

```
line1 = Lines([0,0,2,4])
line1.slope
```

However, when I print `line1.__dict__`, they are not listed in the attributes available.

#### My Question

What I really want to know is if there other (more commonly-used, Pythonic) ways to set attributes to the objects(ex: slope) based on the initial attributes(ex: x1,y1). I thought this would be a very common problem (i.e., having a set of basic attributes as input and then setting other more advanced attributes based on them to the same object) but I've not found not much on it on here. I'm sure I'm missing some simple yet elegant solution here.

Thank you in advance. I hope I was clear with my question.

Comment: The key difference between the two patterns is that using `@property` means the corresponding function is called every time the property is accessed. Setting the property in `__init__` sets them once and doesn't ever recalculate. So you *need* the `property` decorator on a function if you might be changing the base attributes and need those other properties to always be up to date based on them. But if you don't need that then you may as well set them in the constructor, as it will be slightly more performant.

Comment: I don't plan on changing them once they're set. But my question isn't what's better between these two? I want to know the best possible Pythonic solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a couple ways, maybe they are not "common", but they are still `Pythonic`.

## First, The `__dict__`

Consider this simple code:

```
class Lines:
   pass

line1 = Lines()
```

Now, I want to change the attribute `xy`, I mean set it as `10`. Once Python is dynamic and everything in Python is an object, I can do it, look:

```
class Lines:
    pass

line1 = Lines()

line1.xy = 10
print(f"line1.xy = {line1.xy}") #Output: line1.xy = 10
```

What? How can I set an attribute that doesn't exist?! It simple, the `__dict__`. It stores every attribute that is setted through the instance.

```
class Lines:
    pass

line1 = Lines()

line1.xy = 10
print(f"xy = {line1.xy}")  #Output: xy = 10

print(f"__dict__ = {line1.__dict__}")  #Output: __dict__ = {'xy': 10}
```

So, if `__dict__` stores attributes that was setted through the instance, how is the `__dict__` state before I set any attribute?! As you can deduce, it starts empty.

So you should remember that the `__dict__` doesn't show the attributes available, but the attributes that was setted, and it doesn't matter if those attributes exist or not in the `main class`

> However, when I print `line1.__dict__`, they are not listed in the attributes available.

In fact all attributes in `__dict__` are available through it, but if you try to get any other attribute that is not in `__dict__`, but was definided in the class you can get it. HOW? Take a look:

```
class Lines:
    x1 = 3
    x2 = 7

line1 = Lines()

print(f"__dict__ = {line1.__dict__}")  #Output: __dict__ = {}

print(f"x1 = {line1.x1}") #Output: x1 = 3
print(f"x2 = {line1.x2}") #Output: x2 = 7

print(f"__dict__ = {line1.__dict__}") #Output: __dict__ = {}

line1.x1 = 9 #Setting x1, so it will be stored at __dict__
print(f"__dict__ = {line1.__dict__}") #Output: __dict__ = {'x1': 9}

print(f"x1 = {line1.x1}") #Output: x1 = 9
print(f"x2 = {line1.x2}") #Output: x2 = 7

print(f"test = {line1.test}") #Output: AttributeError
```

What is python doing here?! Python first goes to `__dict__` and try to find the attributes `x1` and `x2`, so if it doesn't find them there, then it goes to the `main class`, if it finds them, it returns them for you, if not Python Raise an `AttributeError`.

`__dict__` is awesome, it enables you to do lots of things. Since any attribute value is stored in `__dict__` you can get its value directly by it, look:

```
example = line1.__dict__['x1']
print(f"__dict__['x1'] = {example}") #Output: __dict__['x1'] = 9
```

## Your Issues and Question

The discurss about pythonic code is really insteresting, but we have to ask ourselves if those code are python or not, what I mean if some code are python and there is no `"improvisation"`, so it's pythonic, even if that code are not so commum, for instance the methods `getattr()`, `setattr()` and `delattr()`, some times the use of them are more insterreing than the `"dotted notation"`, because they are more reliable to understand, especially when you have a deep dive in what are doing and you are debugging. (At Least I think like that)

So everything goes around what you are doing and and what you want to do. Imagine you have a high quality code and you use not so common functions, isn't your code Pythonic?! To be clear imagine you are writing a count that is increased every time a transaction is did, so instead you use the common way `count += 1`, you go beyond and use the `itertools.count()`, without doubt you have a high quality code, even if generally people don't use that module, you can see more about it here: [itertools — Functions creating iterators for efficient looping](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html).

So let's go to the code: as you can see it's another way to solve this problem.

```
class Lines: 

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.x1 = points[0]
        self.y1 = points[1]
        self.x2 = points[2]
        self.y2 = points[3]

        self.length = self._length()
        self.slope = self._slope()
        self.y_intercept = self._y_intercept()
    
    def _length(self):
        return round(((self.x2-self.x1)**2 + (self.y2-self.y1)**2) ** 0.5, 2) 
    
    def _slope(self):
        return round((self.y2 - self.y1)/(self.x2-self.x1),1)
    
    def _y_intercept(self):
        return self.y1 - self.slope*self.x1

line1 = Lines([0,0,2,4])
print(line1.length)
print(line1.slope)
print(line1.y_intercept)
```

Your solution using `Read-Only property` are really interesting, actually it even enables to you work with cache too (if we write, of course!), so you don't need calc you attributes `length`, `slope` and `y_intercept` every time you call those variables, you can calc them values only when you change the value of the attribute `points`.

I hope help you, bye!

*`Don't use "improvisation", use Python.`*