# How can I override the value of an object parameter in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to change the given value when I instantiate an object in Python. The arguments are 2 lists (`list_A` and `list_B`) that appear in a GUI. I can manipulate the value of list_A, all the values are boolean-type. I want the `list_B` to show some values, but to be dependent on the values of the `list_A`. 
For example, if the first value of `list_A` is true, then show one half of `list_B`, if the second is true, then show the second half of `list_B`, and if both are true, show the whole list. 
But I need to completely instantiate the object first, in order to read the values of `list_A`, and then modify `list_B`.

I have no access to the class, that's why I cannot modify the workflow, I need to do it this way.

```
instance_var = foo( list_A, list_B ) # this is how I instantiate the object
```

So I don't know if, after the instantiation, I can access and modify `list_B`.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, it would be Foo( list_A, list_B ). It's a class, not a function.

Comment: If you pass `list_A` into the constructor, you already have access to it. So why do you feel like you have to modify `list_B` inside the class instead of before passing it?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can modify the lists before you pass them in; it's not like they're iterators. Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit] the question. Also check out [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "show"?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, at the moment you creat an object and you set any attribute you can access it by `__dict__`, so when you instaciated your `class` you setted two attributes, so they were stored in `__dict__`, which means you can access them, modify them and so on easely through `__dict__`.

Let me show you an example, take a look:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, list_a, list_b):
        self.list_a = list_a
        self.list_b = list_b

    def print_list_b(self):
        print(f'list_b = {self.list_b}')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    list_a = [1, 2, 3] 
    list_b = ["a", "b", "c"]

    p1 = MyClass(list_a,list_b)
    p1.print_list_b()     #Output: list_b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    print(p1.__dict__)    #Output: {'list_a': [1, 2, 3], 'list_b': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
    attr_list_b = p1.__dict__['list_b'] #Getting list_b
    print(attr_list_b)                  #Output: ['a', 'b', 'c']                 

    attr_list_b[2] = "X"    #Modifying list_b
    print(attr_list_b)      #Output: ['a', 'b', 'X']

    p1.print_list_b()       #Output: list_a = ['a', 'b', 'X']
```

As you can see we can easily change the behavior of our classes through `__dict__`.

For a better understanding of `__dict__`, I suggest you read about it in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697925/different-ways-exist-to-create-object-attributes-outside-of-init-method-based-on/59777381#59777381).

> NOTE: YOU CAN USE ALL DICTIONARY' METHODS THROUGH `__dict__`, SINCE IT'S A DICTIONARY.

May help you, bye!